# What are the default values for these export variables?

Tags: linux, sprof

I tried to setup sprof (following this http://greg-n-blog.blogspot.com/2010/01/profiling-shared-library-on-linux-using.html) using the below steps.  Now my program won't run.  What are the steps I need to do to undo the following?

2) export LD_PROFILE_OUTPUT=`pwd`
3) export LD_PROFILE=libmylib.so
4) rm -f $LD_PROFILE.profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, **these steps have nothing to do with your program**.

However, you can re-export the variables to undo the change as below:

```
export LD_PROFILE_OUTPUT=
export LD_PROFILE=
```

but you can not recreate the previous profile that you have removed by

> rm -f $LD_PROFILE.profile

be sure that you replace *libmylib.so* with your library name.

Comment: thanks, I blindly followed instructions, I don't even have a library.